# Rails - validates all blank false but still can't be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model for a Product, I have:

```
 validates :description,        allow_blank: true, presence: false
```

And when I try to seed some Products with the description left blank, I get the following error in my Terminal:

```
rake aborted!
Validation failed: Description can't be blank
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Driving me crazy.

Comment: could you try just commenting out that entire line since you aren't wanting any validations on it?

Comment: Sure, that would fix it. But I want to figure out why allow_blank is not acting like I expect, because I eventually want to validate the format. Just a note - I am getting the same issue for other fields so I want to figure out how I can make the field optional while still validating the format

Comment: Are your setting `description` to an empty string (blank) or nil?

Comment: why are you doing both `allow_blank: true` and `presence: false`? Take out `presence: false`. Also, if all you're doing for validation is `allow_blank: true`, I don't think you need any validation for just that.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_blank), `:allow_blank is ignored by the presence validator.`. I think your issue is caused by using both of them together, either use one or the other.

Comment: Got it, I will just use allow_blank and keep the validations for when I validate the format in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the presence: false. It's not necessary.

If you need a validation later down the road look into [custom validations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/validates_with)

Answer (score 1):

I think You don't need any validation

```
Remove all the validation part
```

Usually, We use `allow_blank: true`, If the model has any validations for length,
If you dont need to validate the presence, Then It makes no sense putting `allow_blank: true` there..